# What is the difference between resources and namespace in rails nested routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What is the difference between

```
namespace :alpha do
  resources :posts
end
```

and

```
resources :alpha do
  resources :posts
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the difference using `rake routes`.

This definition with a namespace:

```
namespace :alpha do
  resources :posts
end
```

results in the following routes:

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                     Controller#Action
    alpha_posts GET    /alpha/posts(.:format)          alpha/posts#index
                POST   /alpha/posts(.:format)          alpha/posts#create
 new_alpha_post GET    /alpha/posts/new(.:format)      alpha/posts#new
edit_alpha_post GET    /alpha/posts/:id/edit(.:format) alpha/posts#edit
     alpha_post GET    /alpha/posts/:id(.:format)      alpha/posts#show
                PATCH  /alpha/posts/:id(.:format)      alpha/posts#update
                PUT    /alpha/posts/:id(.:format)      alpha/posts#update
                DELETE /alpha/posts/:id(.:format)      alpha/posts#destroy
```

As you can see, the only thing that is different from a plain `resources` route set is the addition of `/alpha` prefix.

Now for the two-level `resources` routes definition:

```
resources :alpha do
  resources :posts
end
```

which results in:

```
         Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                               Controller#Action
    alpha_posts GET    /alpha/:alpha_id/posts(.:format)          posts#index
                POST   /alpha/:alpha_id/posts(.:format)          posts#create
 new_alpha_post GET    /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/new(.:format)      posts#new
edit_alpha_post GET    /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/:id/edit(.:format) posts#edit
     alpha_post GET    /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#show
                PATCH  /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                PUT    /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#update
                DELETE /alpha/:alpha_id/posts/:id(.:format)      posts#destroy
    alpha_index GET    /alpha(.:format)                          alpha#index
                POST   /alpha(.:format)                          alpha#create
      new_alpha GET    /alpha/new(.:format)                      alpha#new
     edit_alpha GET    /alpha/:id/edit(.:format)                 alpha#edit
          alpha GET    /alpha/:id(.:format)                      alpha#show
                PATCH  /alpha/:id(.:format)                      alpha#update
                PUT    /alpha/:id(.:format)                      alpha#update
                DELETE /alpha/:id(.:format)                      alpha#destroy
```

As you can see, `alpha` becomes a top-level resource with all 8 RESTful routes. `posts`, in turn, become second-level resource, accessible only through the route to a specific `alpha` object.

Read more in [Rails Routing from the Outside In](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources).

You might also find interesting the `scope` option. Read about the difference between `scope` and `namespace` in [Scoping Rails Routes](http://notahat.com/2014/02/05/scoping-rails-routes.html) blog post.